# Dapper multi mapping set which property is mapped first

Tags: c#, dapper

I have 2 classes Entity and Instance. Instance class has an Entity object and a list of Attributes like this:

```
public class Instance
{
    public Instance()
    {
        AttributeList = new ObservableCollection<AttributeClass>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Attributes
    {
        get => _attributes;
        set
        {
            _attributes = value;
            JsonConvert.PopulateObject(Attributes, AttributeList);
        }
    }

    public Entity Entity
    {
        get => _entity ?? (_entity = new Entity());
        set
        {
            _entity = value;
            for (int i = _attributeList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                _attributeList.RemoveAt(i);
            }
            foreach (Entity.AttributesDescribeClass attributeDescribe in _entity.Attributes)
            {
                _attributeList.Add(new AttributeClass() { AttributesDescribe = attributeDescribe });
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<AttributeClass> AttributeList
    {
        get
        {
            return _attributeList;
        }
        set
        {
            _attributeList = value;
            _attributes=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AttributeList);
        }
    }

    public class AttributeClass
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Entity.AttributesDescribeClass AttributesDescribe { get; set; }
        public string Name
        {
            get => AttributesDescribe.Name;
        }
        public object Value { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public ObservableCollection<InstanceValidator> Validators { get; set; }

        public AttributeClass()
        {
            Validators = new ObservableCollection<InstanceValidator>();
        }
    }
}
```

The only this class can work is Entity is always set first, so that it will create the AttributeList, after that, we set Attributes and Populate AttributeList object. But it seems Attributes always set before Entity so this class can't work. Any way to indicate Dapper.NET to set Entity before Attributes?

Comment: Dapper lets you pass a function parameter to explicitly specify how fields are mapped.  I find that a lot more intelligible than using the automatic mutli-mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dapper processes columns from a reader, left-to-right. So: "whichever field comes back from the database first".